# Auth0 & Express-openid-connect /callback not responding

Tags: node.js, express, openid-connect, auth0

I have a simple node express application running on port 3002 (because 3000 is already used). For logging users in I use Auth0 and the Express-openid-connect package.

Every time I try to log in I get stuck at a blanc page called: *Submit This Form*, but it doesn't stop loading. The logs in Auth0 always show: *successfull login*. I can however access non login-protected routes without a problem.

The /callback route throws the following error:

```
Error: Request aborted
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:122:19)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at abortIncoming (_http_server.js:569:9)
    at socketOnEnd (_http_server.js:585:5)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:412:35)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1334:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
```

but I think that's what it is supposed to do when a request is aborted, right?

My Auth0 setup should be right since it doesn't result in an error.

My Express-openid-connect middleware looks linke this:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const { auth } = require('express-openid-connect')

module.exports = auth({
    authRequired: false,
    issuerBaseURL: process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER_URL,
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
    clientID: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
    secret: process.env.AUTH0_SECRET
})
```

and the env variables:

```
BASE_URL=http://localhost:3002
AUTH0_ISSUER_URL=...
AUTH0_CLIENT_ID=...
AUTH0_SECRET=H+F/0yW/i4X11EDzAFBZE2iaUTy4jBMo3gBWwXRkoY8W3DJ+E24tnt8Q5y+rF7QO
```

AUTH0_SECRET is just a random string but I tried it with the client secret provided by Auth0 and it changed nothing.

AUTH0_ISSUER_URL is the correct url since every request shows up in the logs.

AUTH0_CLIENT_ID is the correct client id since the logs show the correct application.

If I manually go to localhost:3002/callback I get the following expected error:

```
BadRequestError: state missing from the response
    at /workspace/node_modules/express-openid-connect/middleware/auth.js:121:31
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

This means that my /callback route should be reachable and working.

However I can manually copy the parameters and then everything works however this process isn't usefull for production.

I even tried to submit the form manually over the console

```
document.forms[0].submit()
```

but it returned undefined and the page didn't stop loading once again.

So for me there is something wrong with the submit() function of that form.

Comment: Hoping you reset that Auth0_Secret

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of this is that `Express OpenID Connect` wraps and handles most of the things so developers would not have trouble to setup the protocol flow. Meaning, you would not need to access `/callback` by yourself. `auth` from `express OpenID Connect`, once it is added in express app, provides our express app `/login`, `/callback` and `/logout` routes. More you can find here https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/express.

There are 2 points, in your question that i see, which shall be discussed.

1. `The logs in Auth0 always show: successfull login. I can however access non login-protected routes without a problem.`

- You can access your routes because you are logged in. How you can log out? You need `auth0Logout: true,` in configuration object for `auth` function. `Logout` route is provided under the hood by `Express openID Connect` `auth` method https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/express/01-login#logout

2. You should not call `/callback` by yourself, instead it is part of the flow which is provided by the library (express openID Connect). You can download their sample project and try it yourself: https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-express-webapp-sample/tree/master/01-Login. You can see there that `/callback` route is not added by sample project code. Same goes for `/login` and `/logout` routes.

Screenshots after sample project from the link is run:

- when login is clicked sequence is like this: `/login`, `/callback`, and then `/`
  [image]
- in network tab you can see more [image]