Auth0 callback route - visible in requests but not executing related code
I have an express backend to which I added Auth0. I'm also using express-openid-connect to handle most of the work. The problem is that whatever I do, I cannot get the callback route to work. I see it in my network tab, I can get it logged through my middleware on the server, but whatever I put into this route it is not executing. For debugging, I added a redirection and a console.log to /callback route but literally nothing happens after login and the auth0 is just redirecting to the origin of the request (for example when localhost8000/). Below is a truncated version of my server.ts Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm stuck on this for the 3rd day and I'm losing my mind here.
const app: Express = express();
const port = 8000;

export const auth0Config: ConfigParams = {
  authRequired: false,
  auth0Logout: true,
  secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET,
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000',
  clientID: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
  issuerBaseURL: process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
  session: {
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    },
    rolling: true,
    absoluteDuration: 86400, // 1 day
  },
  authorizationParams: {
    scope: 'openid profile email',
  },
};

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false })); // required to handle urlencoded requests
app.use(express.json()); // required to handle form-data request
app.use(cors()); // middleware to enable CORS requests

// middleware to log request to the console
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`Request: ${req.method} ${req.url}`);
  next();
});

app.use(auth(auth0Config));

app.post('/callback', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Callback route reached - TEST 2');
  res.redirect('http://localhost:3000');
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.oidc.isAuthenticated() ? 'Logged in' : 'Logged out');
});


Here are my urls in Auth0 dashboard

EDIT: after checking some examples from the linked github repos, I came up with something like this:
export const auth0Config: ConfigParams = {
  authRequired: false,
  auth0Logout: true,
  secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET,
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000',
  clientID: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
  issuerBaseURL: process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
  session: {
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    },
    rolling: true,
    absoluteDuration: 86400, // 1 day
  },
  authorizationParams: {
    scope: 'openid profile email',
  },
  routes: {
    login: false,
    callback: false,
  },
};

app.get('/login', (req, res) =>
  res.oidc.login({
    returnTo: '/post-login',
    authorizationParams: {
      redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8000/callback',
    },
  })
);



app.post('/callback', express.urlencoded({ extended: false }), (req, res) =>
  res.oidc.callback({
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8000/callback',
  })
);

app.get('/post-login', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Callback route reached - TEST 2 - get');
  res.redirect('/profile');
});


It is messy and I barely understand what I'm doing (especially with those redirectUri but it is working so that's something

Did you see this "related question" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71213565/auth0-express-openid-connect-callback-not-responding?rq=2  ?

Thank you. I didn't see this question. So if I understand correctly, I shouldn't really add a /callback route with a controller. This kind of changes my perception of this callback URL concept. In that case, how can I execute some code post-login? I was thinking about redirecting to a form or checking if the user exists in my database. The whole time I was thinking that this is the purpose of callback URL

Haven't worked with this setup; just saw your question and stumbled over the other question/answer. Here, they have an example which includes the callback route: https://github.com/auth0/express-openid-connect/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md#3-route-customization So it should be possible, what you're trying to achieve.

Isn't the callback a get request instead of a post?

I tried to use both. In my network tab I can see only POST so I left POST

In this example it seems you don't have handle it manually. https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/express -> // auth router attaches /login, /logout, and /callback routes to the baseURL
app.use(auth(config)); -> so no manual callback handling required, only configuration

I get that but how do I customize what the callback is doing? Let's say I want to redirect or fetch user info from my db.

That's not how it works. The callback has another purpose. You can just check req.oidc.isAuthenticated() on your requested route
